# Prettier gives errors on `createAsyncThunks`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, prettier

Prettier gives me a bunch of errors for `createAsyncThunk` code, while TypeScript and ESLint don't catch those. What can cause this?

Examples of errors:
src\store\slices\calendarActionsSlice.ts: SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration. (37:73)

```
export const getDateRangeActions = createAsyncThunk<IInitialState, number, { rejectValue: unknown }>(
```

src\store\slices\calendarSlice.ts: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (54:76)

```
const fetchRoot = createAsyncThunk<{ message: string, calendar: IDayStorage[], rejectedValue: unknown }>(
```

src\store\slices\monitoringSlice.ts: SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration. (41:77)

```
 export const getVacationMonitoring = createAsyncThunk<IVacMonitoring, unknown>(
```

src\store\slices\profileSlice.ts: SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration. (13:65)

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { getResolvedUrl } from "../../utils/getResolvedUrl";
import { responseWithReject } from "../../utils/responseWithReject";

interface IUserInfo {
    dep_name: string
    user_name: string
}

interface IInitialState {
    user_info: IUserInfo
}

export const getProfile = createAsyncThunk<IInitialState, unknown>(
//                                                              ^
    "profile/getProfile",
    async (_, ThunkApi) => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch(getResolvedUrl("profile"), {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: <HeadersInit>{
                "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token"),
            }
        })
        return await res.json()
            ;
    } catch (e) {
        return ThunkApi.rejectWithValue(e)
    }
});

const initialState: IInitialState = {
    user_info: {
        dep_name: '',
        user_name: ''
    }
};

const profileSlice = createSlice({
    name: "profile",
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(getProfile.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.user_info = action.payload.user_info
        })
        builder.addCase(getProfile.rejected, () => {
            responseWithReject()
        })
    }
});

// export const {} = profileSlice.actions
export default profileSlice.reducer;
```

src\store\slices\requestActionsSlice.ts: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (67:88)

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import { getResolvedUrl } from "../../utils/getResolvedUrl";
import { responseWithReject } from "../../utils/responseWithReject";
import { AppDispatch, RootState } from "../index";

export type TRequests = {
    action_name: string,
    date_start: string,
    datetime_create: string,
    days: number
    id: number
    starts_in: number
    vac_id: number
}

interface DataRange {
    date_start: number
    date_end: number
}

interface IMainInterval extends DataRange {
    days: number
}

interface ISecondaryInterval extends DataRange {
    days: number
    description: string
}

export interface IVacAppDetail {
    main_interval: IMainInterval[]
    secondary_interval: ISecondaryInterval[]
}

export interface IAgreementList {
    action_name: string,
    app_id: number
    date_start: string
    datetime_create: string
    days: number
    starts_in: number
    user_name: string
    vac_id: number
}

interface IRequestsDetails {
    error_code: number | null
    error_name: string
    vac_app_detail: IVacAppDetail
}

interface IDeleteResponse {
    error_code: number
    error_name: string
}

interface IInitialState {
    vac_id: number | null
    app_id: number | null
    requests: TRequests[],
    requests_details: IRequestsDetails
    agreementList: IAgreementList[]
}


export const getMyRequest = createAsyncThunk<{ message: string, vac_app_list: TRequests[] }>(
    "request_actions/getMyRequest",
    async (_, ThunkApi) => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch(getResolvedUrl("get_my_vac_app_list"), {
                method: "GET",
                headers: <HeadersInit>{
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token"),
                },
            });
            return await res.json();
        } catch (e) {
            return ThunkApi.rejectWithValue(e)
        }
    });

export const deleteRequest = createAsyncThunk<IDeleteResponse, { vac_id: number, app_id: number }, {
    dispatch: AppDispatch
}>(
    "request_actions/deleteRequest",
    async ({vac_id, app_id}, ThunkApi) => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch(getResolvedUrl("del_my_vac_application"), {
                method: "DELETE",
                headers: <HeadersInit>{
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token"),
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    vac_id: vac_id,
                    app_id: app_id,
                }),
            });
            void ThunkApi.dispatch(getMyRequest());
            return await res.json();
        } catch (e) {
            return e;
        }
    }
);

export const getDetailRequestInfo = createAsyncThunk<IRequestsDetails, unknown, { state: RootState }>(
    'request_actions/get-detail-request-info',
    async (_, ThunkApi) => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch(getResolvedUrl("get_vac_application_detail_info"), {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: <HeadersInit>{
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token"),
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    vac_id: ThunkApi.getState()["request_actions"]["vac_id"],
                    app_id: ThunkApi.getState()["request_actions"]["app_id"]
                })
            })
            return await res.json()
        } catch (e) {
            return e
        }
    }
)

export const getAgreementVacations = createAsyncThunk<{vac_app_list_for_approval: IAgreementList[]}>(
    'request_actions/get-agreement-vacations',
    async (_, ThunkApi) => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch(getResolvedUrl("get_vac_application_list_for_approval"), {
                method: "GET",
                headers: <HeadersInit>{
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token"),
                }
            })
            return  await res.json()
        } catch (e) {
            return ThunkApi.rejectWithValue(e)
        }
    }
)

const initialState: IInitialState = {
    vac_id: null,
    app_id: null,
    requests: [],
    requests_details: {
        error_code: null,
        error_name: '',
        vac_app_detail: {
            main_interval: [],
            secondary_interval: []
        }
    },
    agreementList: []
};

const requestActionsSlice = createSlice({
    name: "request_actions",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        changeRequestId: (state, action: PayloadAction<{ vac_id: number | null, app_id: number | null }>) => {
            state.vac_id = action.payload.vac_id;
            state.app_id = action.payload.app_id;
        },
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(getMyRequest.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            if (!action.payload.message) {
                state.requests = action.payload.vac_app_list;
            } else {
                window.location.href = "/sign-in";
            }
        });
        builder.addCase(getMyRequest.rejected, () => {
            responseWithReject()
        })
        builder.addCase(getDetailRequestInfo.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.requests_details = action.payload
        })
        builder.addCase(getAgreementVacations.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.agreementList = action.payload.vac_app_list_for_approval
        })
        builder.addCase(getAgreementVacations.rejected, () => {
            responseWithReject()
        })
    }
});

export const {changeRequestId} = requestActionsSlice.actions;
export default requestActionsSlice.reducer;
```

Prettier config:

```json
{
    "endOfLine": "auto",
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "printWidth": 100,
    "importOrder": ["^[./]"],
    "importOrderSeparation": true,
    "importOrderSortSpecifiers": true
}
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @possum unfolded some examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `<HeadersInit>`. After deleting it, prettier worked correctly. I'm not even sure what TS syntax it was: `<Type>someObject`